# How can blockchains be used in audit trails?

Tags: audit, blockchain, accounting

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use blockchain in audit trails and potentially in accounting (and if they actually make sense). Both [Deloitte](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/de/Documents/Innovation/Blockchain_A%20game-changer%20in%20accounting.pdf) and [EY](http://www.ey.com/gl/en/services/assurance/ey-reporting-blockchain-and-the-future-of-audit) mention them.

I somehow cannot understand how this could be of benefit for audits and/or accounting.

1. To my understanding to make use of the power of blockchains you need multiple users. Only one user means you cannot validate the integrity since all blocks of that user could be compromised (if one block of a blockchain of a user got changed maybe also all of the following where changed, making it impossible to detect the modification). This means blockchains only make sense if you can share them with different users?
2. Data and thus blockchains however aren't always shared between multiple users. In accounting you often only have one "user"/"owner" of the data. Sure you could create multiple users in one company but there wouldn't be any benefit since they are in one location (company) and potentially all compromised. Or if the admin want's to change something he could easily modify all users making it useless for audits.
3. To make it work you would need different partners (supplier/customer) to share the information with. In that case you could however only have two users share the same blockchain (depending on legal regulations in your country) and then again who do you trust if one of the two doesn't validate?
4. Deloitt mentions that they can be used for files. Again I don't see the benefit since you would need multiple users AND files might get compressed with a different algorithm over time rendering them invalid (the useful information didn't change but the block will still be invalid). Or is this a not an issue from your experience? To me it seems it could be a problem.
5. The same goes for all the internal data which may be important for audits from my point of view. Which company would like to share the information with **independent** users. Or is it only intendet for "public"/"shared" data?
6. To identify a modification of one block in a blockchain the user would have ot validate every single block (every hash in the header of a block needs to be compared to the data of the previous block). In terms of accounting a blockchain could be all transactions of one account during one fiscal year. This however could easily be thousands of transactions. Wouldn't this be very slow to validate?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the point in terms of audit trails but as long as the users are not independent data can always be modified making it useless for audits. And you need a critical mass to share the blockchain with.

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that it's neccesary to get the power of Blockchain. It gives us the chance to create descentralized data bases, i.e. data bases that are not controled by an authority. Also, the data of Blockchain is immutable and permanent, i.e. it can not be modified or deleted. Thanks to it you achive a unique descentralized registry in a distributed network, for example for audit trails.

It's true that it has no sense if you use it inside your company. But if you use it among different companies? Each one could encode its data, so the rest of the companies couldn't see it. However, all the data would be stored in all the companies, so anyone couldn't change it. Moreover, you can have more than one user (node) for each company.

Nowadays, there are many implementations of Blockchain, each one with a different objetive. To understan better the power of Blockchain, I suggest you to wathc the video were is explained the new version [(the v 1.0) of the Hyperledger Fabric.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js3Zjxbo8TM)